# Pointer to functions in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

Is this syntax correct?

`cmp` is a pointer to a function. Everything in my program works ok, BUT :

1. look ! I didn't use `*` when I declared `cmp` in the function. Why does my code work?
2. When I declare it with `int (*cmp)` everything also works great.

What is going on here ??

```
RangeTreeP createNewRangeTree(Element participateWorkers[], int arrsize,
                              int cmp(ConstElement, ConstElement))
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
RangeTreeP createNewRangeTree(Element participateWorkers[], int arrsize,
                  int (*cmp)(ConstElement, ConstElement))
```

?

The call to this `createNewRangeTree` function is :

```
createNewRangeTree(tempArr, NUM_PAR, &teacherCmpSalary)
```

and `teacherCmpSalary` is a regular function that looks like this :

```
int teacherCmpSalary(ConstElement c1, ConstElement c2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either form is correct.

If you define a function parameter that's of function type, as in your first example, it's automatically "adjusted" to be of the corresponding pointer-to-function type.

There's a very similar rule for array parameters; your parameter `Element participateWorkers[]` is exactly equivalent to `Element *participateWorkers`.

(Both of these rules apply only to parameter declarations, not in other contexts.)

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the most recent draft of the 2011 ISO C standard), section 6.7.6.3, paragraphs 7 (for arrays) and 8 (for functions).

It's not possible to have parameters of array or function type, so the syntax is "borrowed" for parameters of the corresponding pointer types.

Personally, I prefer to use the pointer notation because it's more explicit, but you should at least understand both forms, since you're going to see them both in other people's code.